# Horizontal scrolling on Mouse Wheel

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a single row table containing images with horizontal scroll bar, and I want to scroll images horizontally using mouse wheel.
Here is my html.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-gallery">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="images">
          <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_1.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href=" ">Alia Bhatt</a></div> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="images">
          <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_2.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">sonia gandhi</a></div> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="images">
          <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_3.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Barney Stinson</a></div> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="images">
          <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_4.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Ranjit Choudary</a></div> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="images">
          <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_5.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Gangadhar Shastri</a></div> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="images">
          <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mouse Wheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel), a jQuery Plugin to achieve horizontal scrolling.
Mouse Wheel provides two helper methods called `mousewheel` and `unmousewheel` that act just like other event helper methods in jQuery and you code should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="image-gallery">
     <table>
  <tr>
    <td class="images">
      <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_1.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href=" ">Alia Bhatt</a></div> </div>
    </td>
    <td class="images">
      <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_2.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">sonia gandhi</a></div> </div>
    </td>
    <td class="images">
      <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_3.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Barney Stinson</a></div> </div>
    </td>
    <td class="images">
      <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_4.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Ranjit Choudary</a></div> </div>
    </td>
    <td class="images">
      <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_5.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Gangadhar Shastri</a></div> </div>
    </td>
    <td class="images">
      <div class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>
  </div>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

         //The "30" represents speed. preventDefault ensures the page won't scroll down.
         this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();

 });
});
</script>
```

Here is a **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/prf8tg08/1/)**

Comment: there is no horizontal scrolling present in the demo on mouse wheel anymore in 2020..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<div>` to wrap the image and description, use `<span>` because it aligns inline be default.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-gallery">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_1.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href=" ">Alia Bhatt</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_2.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">sonia gandhi</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_3.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Barney Stinson</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_4.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Ranjit Choudary</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_5.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Gangadhar Shastri</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>
        <!-- duplicating it/adding more to get the horizontal scrollbar -->
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>            
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>            
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>            
        <td class="images"><span class="img"><img src="../Images/small_Image_6.jpg" /><div class="description"><a class="image-slider-studets-names" href="">Mountain</a></div> </span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```