# Horizontal scroll with mouse wheel issue

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website with horizontal scrolling.
Searching on the internet I solved nothing, so I ask here.
Is it possible to make the page scroll horizontally instead of vertically when I rotate the mouse wheel? I have disabled the vertical scrollbar from the overflow-y property but nothing has changed.
Thanks.

Comment: 5s google search: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/ and this: https://codeconvey.com/pure-css-horizontal-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal scrolling on Mouse Wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685085/horizontal-scrolling-on-mouse-wheel)